# error while instantiating a class

Tags: c++, object, instantiation

I have a simple question about instantiating an object in C++: 
If we assume that my class has a default constructor, then I create the new object like that:

```
PfAlgorithm object = new PfAlgorithm();
```

but when I run I get this error:

```
conversion from ‘PfAlgorithm*’ to non-scalar type ‘ns3::PfAlgorithm’ requested
```

Can someone explain to me the reason of this error please? 
Thank you very much.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `new` operator returns a pointer, not a value. So you need to write:

```
PfAlgorithm* object = new PfAlgorithm()
```

Where `object` is a pointer to the newly allocated PfAlgorithm object. Some simple introductory information about pointers can be found [here](http://linuxconfig.org/c-understanding-pointers). However as has been discussed in the comments below, it is almost never a good idea to deal in raw pointers (due to potential issues with memory leaks, issues of ambiguous ownership etc). Read on...

Having allocated this object on the heap, you need to make sure you delete it when you're finished with it, otherwise your application will leak memory. In order to make this easier I strongly recoomend you also consider using smart pointers from the [boost libraries](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_50_0/libs/smart_ptr/smart_ptr.htm) (or from C++11) to manage your memory.

Alternatively, as various others have suggested, you can simply do:

```
PfAlgorithm object;
```

And allocate your object on the stack and not have to worry about managing the memory.

Comment: That’s doing it way more complex than necessary. Lose the pointers (and consequently `new`). Given the level of detail the OP has provided, this is simply **not** an acceptable solution.

Comment: @KonradRudolph. OK. I appreciate that pointers are complicated. But, frankly, you're not going to get very far in C++ without knowing a bit about them. So I think it's entirely valid to additionally include a stack allocation (as others have done, and as I have included) but asserting that this is not an acceptable solution is rather extreme.

Comment: @Alex May I direct you to a [deck of presentation slides about pointers …](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/6101039/Modern%20C%2B%2B.pdf). And I stand by my assertion. Memory-owning raw pointers have no place in C++. Code which has them is of low quality.

Comment: @KonradRudolph. Goodness. I agree entirely. But there is a distinction between where you allocated your object (stack/heap) and how you manage it. So by all means advocate `new`-ing directly into a smart pointer, but you seemed to be suggesting stack allocation only in your initial comment.

Answer (score 5):

Is it possible that you are more experienced in Java than in C++? Unlike Java, in C++ you *do not need `new`* when you instantiate an object:

```
PfAlgorithm object;
```

creates an object of type `PfAlgorithm` just fine. That object is automatically destroyed when the variable goes out of scope.

Answer (score 1):

C++ makes a distinction between an object (of type PfAlgorithm in your case) and a pointer to an object (PfAlgorithm *).
The `new PfAlgorithm()` expression returns a pointer to a newly allocated object.  If that is what you want, you must also make `object` have the type of a pointer:

```
PfAlgorithm *object = new PfAlgorithm();
```

If you don't want to use a pointer, get rid of the `new`:

```
PfAlgorithm object = PfAlgorithm();
```

In the first case, you will have to `delete` your object once you no longer use it; in the second case, the object will be destroyed on exit from the block (`{...}`) where it was created.  There is no automatic memory management as in Java or C#.